# jQgrid .clearsearchclass is reloading instead of clearing search field

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

[image: Input search field]

When clicking Reset Search Value `X` pages is redirected to an undefined url, when it should only clear results

I could only debug here from jquery.jqgrid.min.js before the pages is reloaded

```js
a(".clearsearchclass", j).click(function() {
  alert("hello");
  var c = a(this).parents("tr:first"),
    e = parseInt(a("td.ui-search-oper", c).attr("colindex"), 10),
    g = a.extend({}, d.p.colModel[e].searchoptions || {}),
    h = g.defaultValue ? g.defaultValue : "";

  "select" === d.p.colModel[e].stype ? h ? a("td.ui-search-input select", c).val(h) : a("td.ui-search-input select", c)[0].selectedIndex = 0 : a("td.ui-search-input input", c).val(h), 
    b.autosearch === !0 && f()
}),
this.p.filterToolbar = !0, 
  this.triggerToolbar = f, 
  this.clearToolbar = g, 
  this.toggleToolbar = h
```

Comment: How is this related to PHP? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: FYI `,` is not a line-ending in JS. You should be using the semi-colon (`;`) instead. I'd also suggest refactoring that ternary expression as it's borderline unreadable.

Comment: Can you please post example which shows the problem (if possible full example with simple data)? By the way which version of jqGrid is used? - Guriddo jqGrid, free-jqGrid or jqGrid <= 4.7